# setting custom shortcut global in Linux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am used to the following shortcut back when I was on Windows:

Alt + n => Backspace

I used to do that simply with Autohotkey and assigning a global shortcut all over the windows. Is there a way to do that in Linux?

In short, I want a key combination work as if I pressed another key, global in the OS regardless of what application I am using, and I have a lot of them:

Alt + j = left cursor;
Alt + l = right cursor;
Alt + H = home;
Alt + ' = end;
Alt + 1 = Ctrl + Shift + Tab;
Alt + 2 = Ctrl + Tab; and ...

Comment: Global, every where in the OS

Comment: What have you tried? There are quite a few tutorials on this out there.